# How to import classes to a class diagram in Rational Software Architect?

Tags: java, uml

I'm working with IBM Rational Software Architect Standard Edition 7.5.5 trying to create a class diagram from existing source code. I have a project with a bunch of models, diagrams, etc.
I created a new class diagram, but can't figure how to import the existing classes to it. I found a bunch of articles online how to reverse engineer UML class diagrams from Java code, but I can't make any sense of them.
Either they show something that does not exist in my version of the software, or something that does not work ("Visualize -> Add to diagram" method).
Is there a simple method to import .java files in a class diagram?

I also tried creating a new Java project from existing source and running the "Software Annalyzer" on it, but that returns 0 results no matter what rules I set.

Comment: I guess you're bound to RSA (who would pay that price else?). Else you could try RE your source with Enterprise Architect and move the model via XMI. Probably tricky as well since XMI is a per-vendor standard :-P

Comment: RSA is the tool that's being used, I would not have picked it myself.